# Overload BigDecimal's multiply method in Groovy

Tags: math, matrix, groovy, operator-overloading

I've created a class `Matrix` in Groovy, and overloaded the `multiply()` function so that I can easily write things like:

```
Matrix m1 = [[1.0, 0.0],[0.0,1.0]]
Matrix m2 = m1 * 2.0
Matrix m3 = m1 * m2
Matrix m4 = m1 * [[5.0],[10.0]]
```

But now, let's say I write:

```
Matrix m5 = 2.0 * m1
Matrix m6 = [[5.0,10.0]] * m1
```

These two lines produce an error because the classes `BigDecimal` and `ArrayList` cannot be multiplied by a `Matrix`.

Is there a way to overload `multiply()` for these classes? (I know I could just extend these two classes, but then is there a way to tell Groovy to use the extended classes when compiling code?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overload the `multiply()` method in `BigDecimal` and `ArrayList`. Extending the classes will not work as you'd like because Groovy will not create instances of your subclasses from `BigDecimal` and `List` literals.

My first recommendation is to simply stick with the syntax in which the `Matrix` instance is the receiver of the `multiply()` method. Ex: *matrix.multiply(whatever)*. This is to avoid having to create a bunch of duplicate `multiply()` implementations. Ex. *Matrix.multiply(BigInteger)* and *BigInteger.multiply(Matrix)*.

## An example

Regardless, here's an example of how to add matrix math methods to to `BigDecimal` and `List`:

```
Matrix m1 = [[1.0, 0.0],[0.0,1.0]]
def m2 = m1 * 2.0
def m3 = m1 * m2

use(MatrixMath) {
    def m4 = 2.0 * m1
    def m5 = [[5.0,10.0]] * m1
}

/*
 * IMPORTANT: This is a dummy Matrix implementation.
 * I was bored to death during this particular
 * math lesson.
 * In other words, the matrix math is all made up!
 */
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
class Matrix {
    List<List> matrix

    Matrix multiply(BigDecimal number) {
        matrix*.collect { it * 2 }
    }

    Matrix multiply(Matrix other) {
        (matrix + other.matrix)
            .transpose()
            .flatten()
            .collate(2)
            .collect { it[0] * it[1] }
            .collate(2)
    }
}

class MatrixMath {
    static Matrix multiply(BigDecimal number, Matrix matrix) {
        matrix * number
    }

    static Matrix multiply(List list, Matrix matrix) {
        matrix * (list as Matrix)
    }
}
```

This example uses a Groovy Category. I chose a Category to keep the multiply() implementations together in one class.

If a Matrix is little more than a `List<List>`, notice that with this approach you can actually get rid of the `Matrix` class. Instead, you can put all of the `multiply()` implementations into the `MatrixMath` Category, and use a `List<List>` as your matrix.